# How can I wire a motor to operate in forward and reverse using a DPDT switch?

Tags: wiring

[image]

I have a toy tractor I'm trying to rewire. There's a motor and battery (so far so good — nothing complicated here). The problem arises with the two components I've included in this entry. The plunger foot switch is activated by pressing on a toy pedal which propels the tractor forward or backward depending on the position of the rocker switch. With six pins on the rocker and three on the plunger I'm not sure how to properly wire everything together. I'm hoping that someone out there in DIY land has encountered a similar situation. Thanks!

I originally posted this under the DIY exchange but the suggestion was made to post it at this stack exchange site. Please forgive the Amazon posts but they're included for clarification

[image]

Comment: Would it be fair to say that you are asking "How can I wire a motor to operate in forward and reverse using a DPDT switch?"

Answer (score 7):

What you're wanting to do is something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuBDi3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your question is about which pins on the switches are which, that's where a datasheet comes in. Vendors of electronics parts that have datasheets are basically a hard requirement for doing anything with any degree of certainty. (Read: Amazon marketplace is not a good source for this.)

Typically, a DPDT (double pole, double throw) rocker or toggle switch will have the poles (common) terminals in the middle, and to either side its throws. For example, on this [datasheet for a CW Industries GRS-4022-1600](http://switches-connectors-custom.cwind.com/Asset/GRS-4022-XXXX.pdf), the terminals are labeled 1, 1a, 1b, 2, 2a, and 2b.

[image: Diagram from GRS-4022-1600 datasheet]

When the switch is in one position, terminal 1 connects to 1a while terminal 2 connects to 2a. In the other position, terminal 1 connects to 1b while terminal 2 connects to 2b.

*It may be worth noting that if you're ordering other components at the same time and can thus share the shipping cost, it's far better to order from a reputable vendor where you can get the switch I linked for less than $2 USD instead of the insane $9 USD in your link. The datasheet is free!*

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I'll have to find another source to avoid paying an outrageous price! It appears as if I really don't need that center pin on the plunger switch according to the schematic illustrating SW1?

Comment: Presumably the plunger is SPDT (single pole, double throw) so if you only need it to make/break the circuit, you only need to connect wiring from the pole (common) to whichever side suits your purpose (one will likely be normally closed while the other is normally open).

Comment: @edhuff Good sources for this kind of thing include Digikey, Mouser, Newark, and RS Components, among others. Definitely never buy electronic components from Amazon, Ebay, or Aliexpress; you'll pay far more money and get parts of dubious origin and even dubiouser quality.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [this tutorial](https://www.robotroom.com/DPDT-Bidirectional-Motor-Switch.html) regarding a similar switch, power supply and motor to control the direction of motor rotation.  Here's an image from that tutorial:

[image]

Comment: By the way this also works if you swap the positions of the motor and the power supply. Just in case one of them is already wired up

Comment: Thanks! This is so helpful. The plunger switch could be wired between the positive battery pole and the top left pin on the rocker?

Comment: Yes, that would be a great place to put the plunger switch. Also, assuming the switch will be in it's relaxed position when not in use, use the Common (COM) and Normally Open (N.O.) contacts of the plunger switch. This type of labeling is very common.  If not used on your switch, you should be able to try all connection combinations on the plunger switch with little or no difficulties.

Answer (score 3):

This DPDT rocker switch and SPDT foot switch would do.

[image]

Here's the schematic.

[image]

The wiring diagram is as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Because the plunger switch has to be in the mix as it controls a little foot pedal that a child would depress for the actual motion be it forward or backward, could the outer two pins of the foot switch be introduced anywhere in the above schematic?

Comment: Antime Ed! My answer has been edited to include the foot switch.

Comment: Thanks so much! I look forward to wiring this up for my niece's little girl. It makes sense that all three of those pins on the plunger needn't be used as it only really acts as an off-on switch. I was trying to complicate things more than necessary which is my usual MO.

Comment: You're most welcome. Have fun, Ed!

Answer (score 1):

If the tractor is actually a Peg Perego, most of the manuals have a wiring diagram in them, and the manuals are available online at their website (they seem to be reorganizing their website at the moment, so you may need to do a Google search for the specific model).  While you can't necessarily use the pinout directly for the reversing switch unless the one you purchased is sold as a drop in replacement, it will give you an idea of how it was originally wired.  As far as the three pins on the accelerator switch, it is an SPDT switch with the middle pin going one side of the switch and the distant pin going to the battery terminal that isn't going directly to the switch (possibly via a thermal protection device).  The last one comes from the other battery terminal via the thermal protection unit, and is the "automatic braking" function that some of the vehicles have (but the same switch seems to be used on all models, as from their point of view it's more cost effective to use a single switch model). The below diagram is from the John Deere Ground Force Tractor, and while it shows using a complete Peg Perego 2 speed + reverse switching unit, it gives you an idea of how the pedal fits into the system.  [image: Wiring diagram from Peg Perego John Deere Ground Force Tractor]

Comment: Thanks for this input. Interestingly, my tractor has only one motor but the  battery (WP4.5-6 6V 4.5Ah) has "Made for Peg-Perego" on it. From the above schematic, it appears as if one lead goes from one pin on the plunger directly to a terminal on the battery (negative). The other outside pin goes to a thermo protector which I do not have but then on to the positive terminal. The center pin on the plunger throws me off a little as I'm not sure what that center image with the six input/outputs represents. From this schematic, that center pin on the plunger is definitely necessary.

Comment: You have a 6V model, this one is a 12V.  The six pin device effectively is the DPDT switch, but on the 12V models it's internally two DPDT switches. One does the polarity reversing, and the second shifts the motors from series to parallel. You don't need the wire going to the thermo protector, that's only used on the 12V and 24V vehicles.  Go from the battery to the top pin (the one further from the center), then to one of the poles on the DPDT switch.  Connect the other pole to the other battery terminal, then connect the motor  as shown in @v2un's answer.

Comment: One minor thing, you might consider an ON-ON DPDT vs an ON-OFF-ON.  With the ON-OFF-ON, you have the middle position where the tractor won't work, and since the 6V tractors are for young children, they may find this confusing.  You'd want to check and make sure the pinout matched with what you are wiring.

Comment: Thanks so much JDG  . . . . . and welcome! And thanks for the suggestion regarding the alternate switching configuration with just the ON-ON position. Have a great weekend!